# Laravel (Nova 4.0) - Redirect from Controller to Nova Resource Details Page

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-nova

im currently working with laravel/laravel nova. I created a custom modal that shows when a laravel nova action is triggered. This custom modal sends data to a backend controller where the data gets processed/saved. After that i would like to redirect to the details page of the nova resource i just worked with but cant find a way to do so.

I tried to redirect() to the url of the resources details page as a return in the controller. I tried to define a route in web.php and/or api.php on which i could make a RedirectResponse.
Maybe im just not seeing the right way, so some inputs would be appriciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Action::redirect('https://example.com');
```

Doc: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/actions/defining-actions.html#redirect-responses